# Python inputting "-"

Tags: python, python-3.x, error-handling, syntax-error, valueerror

I was just wondering why doesn't except ValueError work when inputting "-".
My code looks something like:

```
try:
  x = int(input(""))
except ValueError:
  print("only int")
```

But when I decide to input - 
it comes as value error.

Comment: Works fine for me

Comment: Are you just entering `-`? If so, that's not a number, which is why you get an exception telling you that's not a number. If you want to treat it as something (0? -1?), you'd need to add some code that does an `if` test either before trying the `int`, or inside the `except` clause.

Comment: rip probably something is wrong with me but anyway thanks

Answer (score 0):

Checked in PyCharm. Everything works fine when typing - or "-". An error appears.

```
C:\Users\Vladimir\PycharmProjects\untitled16\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:/Users/Vladimir/PycharmProjects/untitled16/venv/test.py
```

3.6.4 (v3.6.4:d48eceb, Dec 19 2017, 06:04:45) [MSC v.1900 32 bit (Intel)]

"-"

only int